# What is the correct name of an relationship which is passed to Eloqent `Model::load()`?

Tags: eloquent, orm, eager-loading, relation

I have to models `Photo` and `SizeVariant`. A photo has many size variants, a size variant has exactly one photo as its owner. The tables of the DB follow Eloquents naming scheme and are called `photos` and `size_variants`.

My models look like that (shortened down):

```php
class Photo extends Model {
  protected $with = [ 'size_variants' ];

  public function sizeVariants(): HasMany {
    return $this->hasMany(SizeVariant::class);
  }
}

class SizeVariant extends Model {
  protected $with = ['photo'];
  protected $touches = ['photo'];

  public function photo(): BelongsTo {
    return $this->belongsTo(Photo::class);
  }
}
```

However, when I try to call `$photo->load('size_variants)` on an existing `$photo` object, I receive an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException` exception with message `Call to undefined relationship [size_variants] on model [App\Models\Photo]`.

What is the right name of the relationship? I thought the naming scheme would follow Laravels usual pattern and Laravel magically maps between snake and camel case.

I already tried the all combinations of capitalizing, snake and camel case and plural vs. singular, i.e.  `$photo->load('size_variants')`, `$photo->load('size_variant')`, `$photo->load('sizeVariants')`, `$photo->load('sizeVariant')`, `$photo->load('SizeVariants')` and `$photo->load('SizeVariant')`.

Answer (score 0):

Your relation name that is passed in `with` or `load` contexts should match the name of the relation you defined on your model, which in your case should be `sizeVariants`.

On another note, I would also be careful with always eager loading both relations by defining the `protected $with` property on both models. You'll end up getting timeouts because: your Photo model would be eager loading the SizeVariant models, which would eager load the Photo model, which would eager load the SizeVariant models, which would eager load the Photo model, etc.

You should remove the `protected $with` property and use `with` on your queries or `load` on your models whenever you need the related models instead to avoid this.